# Connecting multiple IMU sensors to arduino DUE

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-due

I need to connect 5 IMU 9250 to Arduino Due. I used the library on this webpage and it works well for only one sensor.

https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/2845/

I need to know if there is a code or library that helps me to turn on all five sensors and get data at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The board you are using only supports two possible i2c addresses so the maximum number of boards you can connect over a single i2c bus is two. The [SparkFun hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mpu-9250-hookup-guide) documents this in the "PTH Connections" section, the pin in question is labelled "AD0/SD0".

Answer (score 1):

Besides I2C, MPU9250 has SPI interface. With SPI, you can connect multiple devices on the same bus. They share data out (shown as SDO in the data sheet), data in (SDI), and clock (SCLK). Each device has its own chip select  (CS) pin. If you want to control 5 devices, you need 8 pins (SDO, SDI, SCLK + 5 CS).

With a quick search, I found [a library](https://github.com/bolderflight/MPU9250) that supports SPI. Maybe you can use it as it is. Or, you can study it and implement your own solution.